# Align numbers in each column in a Summary Statistics table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, threeparttable

I am struggling to vertically align all numbers in each column. Now the numbers in rows "Earnings(RMB)" and "Spouse Earnings(RMB)" stand out. Thank you!

What I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,caption}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize]{noitemsep,left=0pt,label=--}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption*{Table 1 - Summary Statistics}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{d{5}d{5}d{5}d{5}} @{}}
\toprule
Two-Sample T-Test & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Gender} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Means} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-2} \cmidrule(l){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Married Men} & \mc{Married Women} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Raw Difference} & \mc{T-Stat} \\ 
\midrule
Earnings \scriptsize (RMB) \tnote{a} & 47743.48 & 32037.77 & 15705.71 & -10.128^{***} \\
\midrule
Education \tnote{b} & 3.435897 & 3.251876 & 0.184021 & -2.9184^{***} \\
Education \scriptsize (years) & 10.151709 & 9.411576 & 0.740133 & -3.8606^{***} \\
Age & 46.20299 & 44.32583 & 1.87716 & -4.9186^{***} \\
Experience \scriptsize (years) \tnote{c} & 30.05128 &  28.91426 & 1.13702 & -2.3852^{**} \\
Work Time \scriptsize (hours) \tnote{d} & 50.90833 &  47.31458 & 3.59375 & -4.1831^{***} \\
HW Time \scriptsize (hours) \tnote{e} & 1.151755 & 2.251799 & -1.100044 & 20.068^{***} \\
Sleep Time \scriptsize (hours) \tnote{f} & 7.553220 & 7.491119 & 0.062101 & -1.1477 \\
Ability Score \tnote{g} & 17.32105 & 16.38853 & 0.93252 & -3.4604^{***} \\
\midrule
Spouse Education \tnote{h} & 3.254274 & 3.411576 & -0.157302 & 2.5134^{**} \\
Spouse Education \scriptsize (years) & 9.42094 & 10.08896 & -0.66802 & 3.5079^{***} \\
Spouse Earnings \scriptsize (RMB) \tnote{i} & 31377.18 & 48106.67 & -16729.49 & 10.346^{***} \\

\midrule
\emph{N} & {936} & {933} & {1869} & {1869} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\medskip
\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
\item[a] Total income for all jobs in 2018, in RMB (official currency of the PRC)\\
\item[b] Highest educational degree at the time of survey, on a scale of 1 to 8 (1, illiterate/semi-illiterate; 8, doctoral degree)\\
\item[c] Potential experience (in years), an index created using $\max\{Age-Education(years)-6,0\}$ \\
\item[d] Weekly work time (in hours) \\
\item[e] Daily time (in hours) spent on housework on average, an index created using: \\
$\frac{(Hours \ spent \ on \ housework \ during \ weekdays)*5 + (Hours \ spent \ on \ housework \ during \ weekends)*2}{7}$ \\ 
\item[f] Daily sleep time (in hours), an index created using: \\
$\frac{(Hours \ of \ sleep \ during \ weekdays)*5 + (Hours \ of \ sleep \ during \ weekends)*2}{7}$ \\
\item[g] An ability index score created using: $\frac{(Math \ test \ score) + (Word \ test \ score)}{2}$ \\
\item[h] Spouse's highest educational degree at the time of survey, on a scale of 1 to 8 (1, illiterate/semi-illiterate; 8, doctoral degree) \\
\item[i] Spouse's total income for all jobs in 2018, in RMB (official currency of the PRC) \\
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\bigskip\small
Notes: 
\begin{myitemize}
\item ***, **, and * indicate significance at the 1\%, 5\%, and 10\% critical level. 
\item The above results are based on the 2018 round of CFPS (China Family Panel Studies) survey data.
\item The data cleaning procedure includes: only keeping married people, dropping those spouses who are not financially-connected with the family, dropping spouses who are not living in this family currently, dropping people who reported ``missing values'' and negative values for their earnings, and dropping all other ``missing values'' throughout our variables. There are 37354 subjects in the original survey data. We obtain 1896 subjects in our sample, 936 married men, 933 married women, after applying all necessary filters.
\item Considering our sample includes married couples who live together, socio-geographical characteristics such as ``number of children'', ``rural vs. urban'', and ``coastal, more prosperous provinces vs. distant provinces'' will be elaborated later, as we compare different groups based on these characteristics.
\end{myitemize}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I understand the numbers are too large and are pushed towards the left edge, which causes the undesired awkward alignment.

`S` column type from the `siunitx` package apply number formatting similarly to `D` column type. However, `siunitx` lets you suppress both formatting and alignment of a number in individual cells if you enclose cell content within braces `{}`; or apply `\multicolumn{}{}{}`. Then, simple centring and tuning by adding extra space should give the expected effect

[image]

EDIT. I am afraid I have provided an unrelated solution as the question is about vertical alignment.

> I am struggling to vertically align all numbers in each column ...

However, I struggle to understand what you mean here. Your table seems to have the perfect vertical alignment in aforementioned rows. I guess *stand out* means the spacing is larger but this is what `\toprule` and `\midrule` do. Two solutions, you can use: `\hline` with standard spacing and a thin rule; or `\specialrule{}{}{}` from `booktabs` to apply custom spacing around the rules but maintain the same rule width as with `\midrule`

```
# \specialrule{<rule width>}{space above}{<space below>}
\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}
```

The code below has not those changes applied.

The code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}               % dcolumn removed
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize]{noitemsep,left=0pt,label=--}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{5.7}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\newrobustcmd\Tn[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}   % <--- added
\sisetup{                                   % <--- added
    table-number-alignment = center,
    table-text-alignment = center,
    table-align-text-after=false,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption*{Table 1 - Summary Statistics}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{
            @{} l
            *2{S[table-format=5.7]}
            *2{S[table-format=-5.7]}
            @{}
        }
        \toprule
        Two-Sample T-Test & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Gender}         & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Means} \\ 
        \cmidrule(l){2-2} \cmidrule(l){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
                          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Married Men}    & \mc{Married Women} 
                          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Raw Difference} & \mc{T-Stat} \\ 
        \midrule
        Earnings \scriptsize (RMB) \tnote{a} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(\hspace{1em}47743.48\)} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(\hspace{1em}32037.77\)} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(\hspace{2em}15705.71\)} &
            {\(-10.128^{***}\)} \\
        \midrule
        Education \tnote{b}                         &  3.435897  &  3.251876 &  0.184021 & -2.9184\Tn{***} \\
        Education \scriptsize (years)               & 10.151709  &  9.411576 &  0.740133 & -3.8606\Tn{***} \\
        Age                                         & 46.20299   & 44.32583  &  1.87716  & -4.9186\Tn{***} \\
        Experience \scriptsize (years) \tnote{c}    & 30.05128   & 28.91426  &  1.13702  & -2.3852\Tn{**} \\
        Work Time \scriptsize (hours) \tnote{d}     & 50.90833   & 47.31458  &  3.59375  & -4.1831\Tn{***} \\
        HW Time \scriptsize (hours) \tnote{e}       &  1.151755  &  2.251799 & -1.100044 & 20.068\Tn{***} \\
        Sleep Time \scriptsize (hours) \tnote{f}    &  7.553220  &  7.491119 &  0.062101 & -1.1477 \\
        Ability Score \tnote{g}                     &  17.32105  &  16.38853 &  0.93252  & -3.4604\Tn{***} \\
        \midrule
        Spouse Education \tnote{h}                  &   3.254274 & 3.411576 & -0.157302 & 2.5134\Tn{***} \\
        Spouse Education \scriptsize (years)        &   9.42094 & 10.08896 & -0.66802 & 3.5079\Tn{***} \\
        Spouse Earnings \scriptsize (RMB) \tnote{i} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(\hspace{1em} 31377.18\)} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(\hspace{1em} 48106.67\)} &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{\(\hspace{1em}-16729.49\)} &
            10.346\Tn{***} \\
        \midrule
        \emph{N} & {936} & {933} & {1869} & {1869} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    
    \medskip
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \footnotesize
        \item[a] Total income for all jobs in 2018, in RMB (official currency of the PRC)\\
        \item[b] Highest educational degree at the time of survey, on a scale of 1 to 8 (1, illiterate/semi-illiterate; 8, doctoral degree)\\
        \item[c] Potential experience (in years), an index created using $\max\{Age-Education(years)-6,0\}$ \\
        \item[d] Weekly work time (in hours) \\
        \item[e] Daily time (in hours) spent on housework on average, an index created using: \\
        $\frac{(Hours \ spent \ on \ housework \ during \ weekdays)*5 + (Hours \ spent \ on \ housework \ during \ weekends)*2}{7}$ \\ 
        \item[f] Daily sleep time (in hours), an index created using: \\
        $\frac{(Hours \ of \ sleep \ during \ weekdays)*5 + (Hours \ of \ sleep \ during \ weekends)*2}{7}$ \\
        \item[g] An ability index score created using: $\frac{(Math \ test \ score) + (Word \ test \ score)}{2}$ \\
        \item[h] Spouse's highest educational degree at the time of survey, on a scale of 1 to 8 (1, illiterate/semi-illiterate; 8, doctoral degree) \\
        \item[i] Spouse's total income for all jobs in 2018, in RMB (official currency of the PRC) \\
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    
    \bigskip\small
    
    Notes: 
    \begin{myitemize}
        \item ***, **, and * indicate significance at the 1\%, 5\%, and 10\% critical level. 
        \item The above results are based on the 2018 round of CFPS (China Family Panel Studies) survey data.
        \item The data cleaning procedure includes: only keeping married people, dropping those spouses who are not financially-connected with the family, dropping spouses who are not living in this family currently, dropping people who reported ``missing values'' and negative values for their earnings, and dropping all other ``missing values'' throughout our variables. There are 37354 subjects in the original survey data. We obtain 1896 subjects in our sample, 936 married men, 933 married women, after applying all necessary filters.
        \item Considering our sample includes married couples who live together, socio-geographical characteristics such as ``number of children'', ``rural vs. urban'', and ``coastal, more prosperous provinces vs. distant provinces'' will be elaborated later, as we compare different groups based on these characteristics.
    \end{myitemize}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!